# Loading the target tables 

Tags: informatica-powercenter

If suppose I have source with seven records from that first three must go in 3 target instances and 4th record again have to go into first target how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve this result.

[image: PowerCenter mapping]

I use a sequence transformation to generate a series of numbers (starting with 1., increment by 1..).

I then route the table rows into one of the three targets based on this sequence number (using mod(nextval,3)) which will result in 0,1 or 2. Here are the three groups for the Router.

```
Group 1 : MOD(NEXTVAL,3)=0
Group 2 : MOD(NEXTVAL,3)=1
Group 3 : MOD(NEXTVAL,3)=2
```

Also, could you please explain why you need the table be loaded into multiple instances?
I have never really come across such scenarios before.